# Continuos Integration on Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

Hi I will be asking a few dumb questions here but please help me out.
I was going through the WWDC video of continuous integration for Xcode. It recommended using "OS X" server to setup the continuos integration. But as per my limited knowledge Jenkins is also a CI server. So my questions are

1. Can we set up the CI for Xcode on Jenkins ?
2. What advantages/disadvantages it has as compared to setting it up on OS server?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both Jenkins and OS X / Xcode server are capable of running iOS continuous integration for your project. Both of these are self hosted (you'll have to install it for yourself, set up on your own machine).

The important things is: Jenkins is not limited to iOS / OS X continuous integration, you can use it for other platforms (for example for Android projects) but the Xcode CI server has more features for iOS CI as it's Apple's official solution.

Another note is: you can use hosted CI services too where you don't have to deal with the server setup - an example is [Bitrise](http://www.bitrise.io/) (founder here) where you can register a free account.